# Angular Accordian with short description

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to use accordian in angular which can show a shor description of the content. And when you click on it, it should show the full description. So basically i need to slice the content and show it in the header. But i am unable to do so. Below is my code, as you can see I have announcement.title in teh heading. However i need to add part of announcement.content in the heading. So i need to slice the content for upto a few characters and show it in the heading. Then when someone click on it, i show the full content. I am not sure how to achieve this. Can someone help ?

HTML code :

```
<accordion>
    <div *ngFor="let announcement of announcements; let i = index">            
            <accordion-group [heading]="announcement.title">
                <div class="announcement-body" [innerHTML]="announcement.content"> {{ announcement?.content }}
                </div>
            </accordion-group>     
    </div>
</accordion>
```

TS file:

```
announcements: any[] = [];
 ngOnInit() {
    this.showAnnouncements();
  }
  showAnnouncements() {
    this.configService.getAnnouncements().then(
      (data: any) => {
        for (const key in data) {
          this.announcements.push({
            title: data[key].title,
            content: data[key].content
          });
        }
      }
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzy8A.png)

I also need the title and the sliced content to appear in the heading on different lines with different font.

Answer (score 0):

You can append some portion of your content to the title using the string slice method.  For example:

```
this.announcements.push({
    title: data[key].title + data[key].content.slice(0,10),
    content: data[key].content
});
```

This would add the first 10 characters of your content string to your title.

If you wanted some fixed length, you could do something like:

```
title: data[key].title + data[key].content.slice(0,MaxLength - data[key].title.length)
```

For the last case, you'd have to ensure that your title is always below max length or protect the slice from going negative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be possible to have the title content with different font size and on a separate line within the heading?

Comment: Which library are you using for the accordion component?  My suspicion is that you cannot - it depends on how the component is handling the input.